# Android - How to relink app data with contacts after changing phones/resetting phone

Tags: android, contacts, android-contacts, contactscontract

**Question**

*How to relink my apps internal data to the new local contacts database, after getting a new phone or after factory resetting the phone?*

**Informations**

My app uses the phones contacts and links all it's internal data to the contacts via the id.

After the user factory resets the phone or gets a new phone, normally the first thing they do is syncing there contacts with google again. The result is a new local contacts database with NEW IDs, so all my internal linkings to this contacts are broken.

Is there a way to restore them? Currently I offer an export/import solution that tries to rematch the contacts based on name + numbers, but I'm interested if there is another way, a better way that always works...

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to restore the row ids and you should not rely on them as a reference in your application. The row id is only a unique identifier in the context of this particular contacts database.

You probably want the [SOURCE_ID](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.SyncColumns.html#SOURCE_ID) field of a raw contact, which is supposed to depend on the sync source and therefore should be the same after a factory reset or on a different device. But even that's not guaranteed as it's up to the sync adapter to decide that.

Also, you should be aware that some sync adapters might not set/use this field at all, even though it's good practice. Android won't complain if it's not set.